# No trusted certificate found using CAS and JBoss

Tags: jboss, certificate, cas

I'm trying to authenticate through CAS+LDAP in a Jboss app. The config is like this:

- Server 1: Jboss 6.10. Cas is deployed here.
- Server 1: LDAP using OpenDS.
- Server 2: Jboss whith the app to login into.

I've configured both jboss to use SSL correctly and the CAS succesfyuly reads and authenticates against the LDAP.

When I get to (through https) server1:8443/app/ i'm redirected to server2:8443/cas/ and the login screen is displayed. I login with a valid user on the LDAP but when the flow gets back to the app i'm always getting this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

I've read its a certificate problem and, as it is a dev enviroment i'm trying the self-signed certificate. So I did this:

1. Gen the self signed in Server1 with

   keytool -genkey -alias jbosskey -keypass password -keyalg RSA -keystore server.keystore
2. Get the certificate of the Server1 with:

   keytool -export -alias jbosskey -keypass password -file server.crt -keystore server.keystore
3. Copy the server.crt to Server2 and import it to the truststore of Jboss.

   keytool -import -alias server1 -file server.crt -keystore C:\dev\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server.truststore
4. This gets me the eception. So I also imported to the cacerts of the JVM.

   keytool -import -alias server1 -file server.crt -keystore C:\dev\jdk160_18\jre\lib\security\cacerts
5. Not working, so I tried to add the certificate to the keystore of the Jboss at Server2.

   keytool -import -alias server1 -file server.crt -keystore C:\dev\jboss-6.1.0.Final\keystore.jks

The Server1 Jboss server.xml

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="${jboss.web.https.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.keystore"
       keystorePass="password" sslProtocol = "TLS" 
/>
```

The Server2 Jboss server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
            scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
            keystoreFile="C:\dev\jboss-6.1.0.Final\keystore.jks"
            keystorePass="password"
            truststoreFile="C:\dev\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server.truststore"
            truststorePass="password"
            sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days and don't know if i'm missing something. Did I missed something important with the keytool?

Thanks in advance.